# How to randomly select a video and play?

Tags: php, jquery, echo

Im learning JQuery and php.

Is it possible to store multiple video links within  variables and get php to echo one at random??

My goal is to control my own video ads on my site and I thought this would be a good idea but I dont have a clue where I should look online.

Here is what I was thinking

```
<?php 

 $advert1 = 'MyVIDEO1.mp4';
 $advert2 = 'MyVideo2.mp4';
 $advert3 = 'MyVideo3.mp4';

 I want a code that would go here and say: randomly select one of these vars.

 echo "At random one of the vars";

?>
```

I hope Im making sense. help?

Comment: var is for javascript and $ is for php first change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an array, like this:

```
$advert[] = array();
$advert[1] = 'MyVIDEO1.mp4';
$advert[2] = 'MyVIDEO2.mp4';
$advert[3] = 'MyVIDEO3.mp4';

$chosen_one = rand(1,count($advert));

echo $advert[$chosen_one];
```

Comment: THIS WORKED PERFECTLY. On my test. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-rand.php) instead of [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.shuffle.php):

```
<?php
$videos = array("MyVIDEO1.mp4", "MyVideo2.mp4", "MyVideo3.mp4");
echo $videos[array_rand($videos)];
?>
```

For embedding the video in the right way, have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp

Answer (score 0):

For a start, PHP itself won't exactly play a video.  You could use it to echo out one of the URL's to a video.  So, bear in mind there is a lot more to do than just select a video.

To answer your question in the code I'd recommend the following:

Try looking up PHP [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).  You want to keep all the videos in an array.
Next up, you'll want to [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) that array. Then select the first element.

```
$videos = array("MyVIDEO1.mp4", "MyVideo2.mp4", "MyVideo3.mp4");
shuffle($videos);
echo $videos[0];
```

Comment: Thank you. If I put the iframe code into a mySql database and tell php to echo will that be better?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution

Place your adverts in an array

```
<?php
$adverts = array("advert1" => "MyVIDEO1.mp4",
                 "advert2" => "MyVIDEO2.mp4",
                 "advert3" => "MyVIDEO3.mp4");

$count = count($adverts);
$rand_advert = rand(1, $count);
echo $adverts['advert'.$rand_advert];
?>
```

Or alternatively if you don't want to have keys and just put the values in the array straight away

```
<?php
$adverts = array("MyVIDEO1.mp4",
                 "MyVIDEO2.mp4",
                 "MyVIDEO3.mp4");

shuffle($adverts);
echo $adverts[0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have need all value in a array then find index randomly and show it.

```
<?php 

$advert  = array(
        'MyVIDEO1.mp4',
        'MyVideo2.mp4',
        'MyVideo3.mp4'
    );

$total_video = count($advert);

$total_video--; //array index starting from 0 so decrease 1

$random_index = rand(0, $total_video); //array index 0 to 2

$video_to_play = $advert[$random_index];

echo $video_to_play;

?>
```